# How do I capture the HTTP code of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, http, iframe

I would like to catch the HTTP code of an iframe. Depending on the HTTP code the iframe must continue/stop loading. Is there any way to do this, using Jquery etc? Or should I use Curl first to check the HTTP code and then load the iframe?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using XmlHttRequest to load your "iframe" :

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
        if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
            // success
            document.getElementById('iframeId').innerHtml = httpRequest.responseText;
        } else {
            // failure. Act as you want 
        }
    }
};
httpRequest.open('GET', iframeContentUrl);
httpRequest.send();
```

No need to use jquery just for this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but then I'm restricted to my own server:
Origin X is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin